# How to prevent the white/black background from appearing when the keyboard pops up on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I've created a demo on CodeSandbox ([Source Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-frog-bb0hfh?file=/index.html:0-1596) | [Live Demo](https://bb0hfh.csb.app/)) for a similar issue that happens to the web app that currently I'm working on.

On mobile browsers (either Android Chrome, iOS Safari, ...etc) when there is input at the bottom of the page when the user focuses it the Keyboard will pop up but with a white background behind it (or black background in case the browser theme is dark).

How can I prevent this white/black background from appearing and instead make the website background appear? (in my case the gradient blue-purple background should appear instead)

[image: gif image showing the issue]

```css
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    *,
    *::after,
    *::before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1e88e5 0%, #673ab7 100%);
    }
    
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    }
    
    .chat-log {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding: 12px 24px;
    }
    
    .message-form {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      padding: 24px;
    }
    
    .message-input {
      padding: 12px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #e2e8f0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="chat-log">
    <h1>Chat</h1>
  </div>
  <form class="message-form">
    <input class="message-input" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Overflow colors are usually handled by the definition on the `body` or `html` element, if that doesn't work I fear it's just a rendering glitch when the keyboard pops out.

Comment: @somethinghere Thanks for the note, but the demo already set the background on the `body` and the issue still persists I've also tried to set it for `html` instead of the body but that didn't work either.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this issue happens on the plain background too. Also, it happened on every device I tested the above demo with. even iPhone 14 whose performance is faster compared to other some devices.

Comment: Is there any evidence this is solvable then? I don't think so - its just the browser window being shrank and or cut off, I highly doubt you have control over that color if defining it on the html or body element does not solve it. I'd be curious to see answers to this, though.

Comment: @somethinghere me either, I don't think this issue is solvable. It's just my Upwork client asked me to fix it and I searched and thought a lot and I didn't find any fix for it. So I just asked here just in case maybe there is a solution I'm not aware of.